# Jquery append .header to thead tr th

Tags: jquery, html-table, traversal

Currently there is a tr.header td but I need it to be in the empty thead tr th

```
$("#new table tr.Header td").each(function(){
  $(this).appendTo("thead tr th");
});
```

This works actually but the problem I have is that multiple tables exist in the DOM. I don't need every single header in all the headers. I just need each table's tr.header to get appended to the thead tr th.  Header 1 will get appended to the table 1's thead...and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Current result is:

```
<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Header 1 Header 2 Header 3 Header 4</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td>
   Row 1
  </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
   Row 2
  </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
   Row 3
  </td></tr>
</tbody> 
</table> 

<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Header 1 Header 2 Header 3 Header 4</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td>
   Row 1
  </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
   Row 2
  </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
   Row 3
  </td></tr>
</tbody> 
</table> 

<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Header 1 Header 2 Header 3 Header 4</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td>
   Row 1
  </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
   Row 2
  </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
   Row 3
  </td></tr>
</tbody> 
</table> 

<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Header 1 Header 2 Header 3 Header 4</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td>
   Row 1
  </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
   Row 2
  </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
   Row 3
  </td></tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Without any jQuery the tables all appear like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr class="Header"><td>
   Header 1
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
   Row 1
  </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
   Row 2
  </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>
   Row 3
  </td></tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: Totally not clear what you want.  Do you want it to look like what you show?  If so, what does it look like before the change?

Comment: @Hogan, I believe he wants something like in my answer(took me three times to read that...)

Comment: Sorry to be unclear. I modified question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must say that it's one of the most unusual things that people asks here, but here you go:

```
$("table tr.Header td").each(function(){
  $(this).appendTo($(this).closest('table').find('thead tr th'));
});
```

Comment: I agree gdoron. This is a rather annoying table that needs to have a  sorting script as well (tsort). This is why i need the table in correct format.